# magento loads catalog/product/view.phtml twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to create a magento side bar box that can list products in certain category.

I have created a file that creates a list of products in a certain catagory called most_sold_list.phtml with the following contents...

```
    <?php
        $_productCollection_1 = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    ?>
    <div class="link_list_with_title">
        <p class="catagory_title">Best Sellers</p>

        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection_1 as $_product_1): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product_1->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_product_1->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product_1->getName(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I then update my local.xml to contain (within `<default><reference name="left">`)...

```
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="most_sold.leftnav" template="most_sold_list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>18</category_id></action>
    </block>
```

This add the block to the page as I would expect. But when I go to the products page I get the following error...

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_quatity_weight_string_view() (previously declared in /.../app/design/frontend/superchef/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:37) in /.../app/design/frontend/superchef/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 54
```

I have checked and that function is not declared anywhere else and this error message goes away as soon as I remove my new block. Also note line 54 is the closing brace of the function.

I have tried removing that function completely by putting its code inline but then I just get the magento error message page.

The only conclusion I can come to is that view.phtml is being loaded twice. I have searched for this and I have seen mentions of zend loader loading files twice.

Can anybody help me fix this, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why are you putting some layout XML update in the local.xml ?? that's a config file not a layout file (OK it works but it's totally the wrong place to put that). Next you define a ph function in a template ?? don't you know about the Block layer ? I think you should learn about magento a bit before trying to code anything.

Comment: Can you point me to somewhere that tells me these things. All the documentation I have read says its best to put things in local.xml.

Comment: app/etc/local.xml is only more global project configuration. For layout update, you must put your code in your specific module layout XML file (app/design/<area>/<package>/<template>/layout/<module>.xml). Go here to learn : http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/development and google

Comment: I have just realised we are talking about different local.xml files. I am talking about app/design/frontend/<theme-name>/default/layout/local.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now worked out how to solve this problem from reading this:
http://www.bwigg.com/2010/01/magento-featured-products-in-sidebar/

So here is what I have done incase anybody else hits this weird problem.

update the layout xml file so the block type is "catalog/navigation".

So it now looks like this...

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="most_sold.leftnav" template="most_sold_list.phtml">
            <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>18</category_id></action>
 </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <remove name="category.products" />
```